# Why would a PHP image copy and resize script cause a browser to return "Content Encoding Error"?

Tags: php

I have a PHP script that takes an images, checks type and filesize, then creates 2 resized copies of the master image, all 3 images are saved to the server. I was under the impression everything worked fine.  I was testing out script and on one jpg image I got thrown the error "Content Encoding Error" by firefox. Doing some reading suggested this was a Firefox issue  but testing in IE and Chrome resulted in similar errors.

The odd thing is that some .jpg files work, others don't. For those that don't work the error is occurring when the script comes to encode the second resized copy as the master, and first copy are outputted to specified folder. I have checked to see that the image itself isn't corrupt after doing some more reading.  The only difference I could note between a .jpg that would allow the script to complete fully and one that wouldn't was that, when viewing the properties of the failing one within Windows it appeared to carry more data, such as camera used to, model number, etc.

Does anyone know what might be causing this error to be thrown?

EDIT

Here's the code I'm using.

```
$imgsrc = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
imagecopyresampled($thbout,$imgsrc,0,0,0,0,$thbwid,$thbhei,$width,$height);
imagejpeg($thbout,$thbpath,80);
imagedestroy($thbout);
imagecopyresampled($optout,$imgsrc,0,0,0,0,$optwid,$opthei,$width,$height);
imagejpeg($optout,$optpath,80);
imagedestroy($optout);
```

Having played about a bit tonight I got it working, by switching the code to this. (Switch to create larger file first)

```
$imgsrc = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
imagecopyresampled($optout,$imgsrc,0,0,0,0,$optwid,$opthei,$width,$height);
imagejpeg($optout,$optpath,80);
imagedestroy($optout);
imagecopyresampled($thbout,$imgsrc,0,0,0,0,$thbwid,$thbhei,$width,$height);
imagejpeg($thbout,$thbpath,80);
imagedestroy($thbout);
```

So I guess my new question becomes, why does it behave like this?

Comment: Without code its just a guess, but the only time ive seen this is when you output from the buffer (or even an error) then try and send the rest of the page/content as gzipped.

Comment: What happens if you strip the metadata from one of your failing images and run your code again? Metadata is supposedly lost when using standard PHP image resize functions so it shouldn't be able to cause a problem (if those are the functions you are using to resize that is)...

Comment: I'm stuck away from my desk for a while but will edit the question with code asap. @pebb I'll try that asap and provide feed back

Comment: @pebb Tried that, and had no effect. Got it working now, as detailed above. Wondering if you can shed any light on the new question? Thanks

Comment: I'm afraid you've got an odd one there :S The only thing I could make a guess at would be that executing them in different orders might affect the memory usage. When you had problems with the images did you ever get any 'not enough' memory errors? also, in your code above there is no definition for `$thbout` and `$optout` I'm assuming you are using `imagecreatetruecolor` and defining them to be the right sizes?

Comment: @pebb no memory errors, and yes I was using `$thbout = imagecreatetruecolor($thbwid,$thbhei);` and `$optout = imagecreatetruecolor($optwid,$opthei);`. The heights and widths were created maintaining the aspect ratio. I happy to move on from this now it works, but wanted to be sure that I wasn't doing something wrong. No point learning the wrong way. Thanks for your time and input.